# What does $\pi_1(X) = 1$ mean?

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness, fundamental-groups

I recently read Kosinski's Differential Manifolds and came across $\pi_1(X) = 1$ a few times. I know what the fundamental group is, I know that if the fundamental group corresponds to a singleton set, it is trivial. In other words, $X$ is simply connected.

But I am not sure whether $\pi_1(X) = 1$ is equivalent to $\pi_1(X) = \{pt\}$ or $\pi_1(X) = 0$. I have not too much experience in algebraic topology to spot equivalent meanings of different notations.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's a notational convention about abelian vs non-abelian groups. When we talk about abelian groups we use additive notation, so the group operation is denoted "$+$" and the neutral element/trivial group are denoted "$0$". On the other hand we often use multiplicative notation for groups that aren't necessarily abelian, such as $\pi_1(X)$, so that the group operation is denoted "$\cdot$" and the neutral element/trivial group is denoted "$1$".

Comment: thank you so much @William!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name itself says, the fundamental group is a group. The notation $\pi_1(X)=\{pt\}$ has no sense if you don't endow the group with a topology. On the other hand $\pi_1(X)=0$ means that the group is trivial, that is contains only the neutral element. Such an element, is denoted with $0$ in the additive notation. In the multiplicative notation is denoted with $1$. It is a purely conventional fact here.

Comment: It still makes sense to say something like $G = \{pt\}$ even if $G$ has no topology. It just says that $G$ has one element, and therefore must be the trivial group. (Also note that the set $\{pt\}$ has a canonical topology anyway)